# Test Java/Kotlin object against avro schema

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, avro

I have a database which saves data after checking it against an avro schema.
Sample avro schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "namespace": "com.test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Before making an actual call to save the data to the database, I am creating a Kotlin object.
Sample data class

```
data class TestData(
 val id: String,
 val name: String
)
```

In the unit tests, is there a way to test the Kotlin object against the avro schema so that there won't be any issues while trying to save the data?